# Heroku Push - Invalid path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, osx-lion, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am relatively new to Rails (on version 3.2.1, on Mac OS 10.7.3 Lion), having successfully gone through Michael Hartl's Rails tutorial and using Heroku, etc. After completing the tutorial I created an account with a new e-mail on Heroku, but since moving on and creating another app I have then have run into deployment problems. Specifically, after pushing the new app to github, when I try "git push heroku master" I get this error from the command line:

```
 !  Invalid path.
 !  Syntax is: git@heroku.com:<app>.git where <app> is your app's name.
```

Having looked over the discussions here and online it appears that I need to play with the settings in my .git/config file. The problem is that this file (/.git/config) doesn't have the settings described in the documents here -- something that would look like the name of my remote file. That file looks like this:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    worktree = /
    ignorecase = true
```

Does anybody know how I can go about finding the file that might enable me to fix this problem with Heroku, or have a better suggestion for how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

What is the output if `git remote -v`? If it only shows the GitHub remote, you need to add your Heroku remote: `git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:app.git` (replacing `app` with your app name).

Comment: I fixed this problem by finally figuring out that my gitconfig file and github account all were set to one e-mail, but my terminal login with heroku was set to a different e-mail. This fixed it: set gitconfig e-mail (development machine), github account, and heroku account all to the same e-mail. I had thought that heroku was using the development login e-mail, but I think it's checking with github's e-mail.